# Not able to download a file in php. Filename passed through url

Tags: php

I am just a beginner with PHP. I am trying to download an image file when a url is clicked.

When I hardcode the filename it works, however when I try to download different image files based on the url clicked, it does not work. The code might explain it in a better way.

Code when a url is clicked

```
<a href="./download.php?var=./img/Photo6.jpg" class="btn btn-2">Download brochure</a>
```

download.php

```
<?php   
$var=$_GET['var'];
$filename=$var;
$filename = './img/Photo6.jpg'; // this works
//$filename = $var; // this does not work
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Cache-Control: private', false); // required for certain browsers 
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. basename($filename) . '";');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));

readfile($filename);

exit;
?>
```

Kindly help.
Thanks.

Comment: Is the value of `$var` what you expect it to be?

Comment: Keep in mind that `./path/to/file` is equivalent to `path/to/file`. `./` does _nothing_.

Comment: didnt understand you completely but I pass var=./img/Photo6.jpg . When I use filename=./img/Photo6.jpg, it works.

Comment: In `download.php` do: `var_dump($var); exit;` Does it print the string you expect?

Comment: I am getting this. Not sure if this is fine. I dont know much of php.
string(16) "./img/Photo6.jpg"

Comment: i tried your code out and i was able to download a file without any issues. are you getting any error when you don't hard code it?

Comment: I am not sure what was the issue. I did not change anything. I had to  restart my xampp due to some reason. But now files are getting downloaded. Thanks everyone. Will upvote your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

when you use:

```
$_GET['var'];
```

You are expecting a url construct with an ? inside it:

```
./download.php?var=./img/Photo6.jpg
```

in your sample: var=./img/Photo6.jpg, tells to php the variable GET[var] will take the value ./img/Photo6.jpg

so, your different image files based on the url clicked, must have the

```
./download.php?var=XXX
```

structure to work. Be sure all your urls has that structure.